# Query not updating in nuxt

Tags: javascript, async-await, nuxt.js, prismic.io

I have a search page in my nuxt project with a search field.

When I type a search word and submit, it sets a query param to the URL `/search/?q=searchword` but the page isn't updating when I make a new search. It updates the q parameter but asyncData isn't called to fetch the results.

I have tried to set `watchQuery: ['q']` to no avail.

I have this asyncData

```
async asyncData({ $prismic, params, query, error }) {
    try {
        // Query to get post content
        const products = await $prismic.api.query($prismic.predicates.fulltext('my.product.title', query.q), { orderings: '[my.product.title desc]' })
        // Returns data to be used in template

        return {
          products: products.results,
        }
    } catch (e) {
      // Returns error page
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
    }
  },
```

and I have set this

```
  watchQuery: ['q']
```

Obviously, I am missing something, but I can't figure out what.

EDIT with HTML

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="q" :value="fieldValue" placeholder="Type and hit enter" />
        </form>
        <div v-if="!!fieldValue" class="num-results">Found {{ products.length }} {{ products.length === 1 ? 'product' : 'products' }}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="search-result">
        <ProductList v-if="products.length !== 0">
          <ProductWidget v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" :product="product" />
        </ProductList>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you make a new search

Comment: @Ifaruki - I have update my question with HTML. I just make a new search with the input field

Comment: you binded your fieldValue but its doing nothin

Comment: fieldValue are set in a method (setFieldValue) . That works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asyncData only runs on page load. So updating the value of `q` will not trigger another call to your API— you’ll need to build a method to handle that.

```
<form @submit="callAPI">
  <input type="text" :value="fieldValue" placeholder="Type and hit enter" />
  <button type="submit">New Search</button>
</form>
```

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    callAPI() {
      try {
        // Query to get post content
        let products = await // api call code...
        
        this.products = products.results,
        
    } catch (e) {
      // Returns error page
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Looked at it completely wrong. Used your answer to make a solution and just query the API on form submit and not on page load. Don't know what I was thinking :)

Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happens sometimes. I spent hours last night debugging a nuxt issue— I’d forgotten the mounted() lifecycle hook doesn’t run on the server. Moved to asyncData, problem instantly solved, then ran through the standard “why do I always do this” shame spiral. Web dev is fun :)